# Kivy: How to separate background touch from a widget touch?

Tags: python, kivy

In my app, I want to handle background touches and widget touches separately. The [Widget documentation](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#widget-touch-event-bubbling) ignores how to prevent bubbling from .kv events. Here's a little test case:

```
from kivy.app import App

class TestApp(App):

  def on_background_touch(self):
    print("Background Touched")
    return True

  def on_button_touch(self):
    print("Button Touched")

if __name__ == "__main__":
  TestApp().run()
```

And the .kv:

```
#:kivy 1.8.0

BoxLayout:
  orientation: "vertical"
  on_touch_down: app.on_background_touch()
  padding: 50, 50

  Button:
    text: "Touch me!"
    on_touch_down: app.on_button_touch()
```

The result: touching either the background or button triggers both handlers. Should I perform collision detection, or is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wanted a solution that allows me to bind events from `.kv` files. [@inclement](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.walk) solution won't allow me to do that because once you bind the event from `.kv`, you can't return `True` anymore to tell the parent you handled the event:

```
Button:
  # you can't return True here, neither from the handler itself
  on_touch_down: app.button_touched()
```

So what I've done is to perform collision detection at the parent, emitting a custom `on_really_touch_down` only if it doesn't hit any children, and performing collision detection yet again at the child, because all children receive the touch regardless of whatever (it's a mess, I know). Here's the complete solution (requires **Kivy >= 1.9.0**, because of the usage [walk](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.walk) method):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class CustomTouchMixin(object):

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(CustomTouchMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.register_event_type("on_really_touch_down")

  def on_really_touch_down(self, touch):
    pass

class CustomTouchWidgetMixin(CustomTouchMixin):

  def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
      self.dispatch("on_really_touch_down", touch)
    return super(CustomTouchWidgetMixin, self).on_touch_down(touch)

class CustomTouchLayoutMixin(CustomTouchMixin):

  def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    for child in self.walk():
      if child is self: continue
      if child.collide_point(*touch.pos):
        # let the touch propagate to children
        return super(CustomTouchLayoutMixin, self).on_touch_down(touch)
    else:
      super(CustomTouchLayoutMixin, self).dispatch("on_really_touch_down", touch)
      return True

class TouchHandlerBoxLayout(CustomTouchLayoutMixin, BoxLayout):
  pass

class TouchAwareButton(CustomTouchWidgetMixin, Button):
  pass

class TestApp(App):

  def on_background_touch(self):
    print("Background Touched")

  def on_button_touch(self, button_text):
    print("'{}' Touched".format(button_text))

if __name__ == "__main__":
  TestApp().run()
```

The `.kv`:

```
#:kivy 1.9.0

TouchHandlerBoxLayout:

  padding: 50, 50
  on_really_touch_down: app.on_background_touch()

  TouchAwareButton:
    text: "Button One"
    on_really_touch_down: app.on_button_touch(self.text)

  TouchAwareButton:
    text: "Button Two"
    on_really_touch_down: app.on_button_touch(self.text)
```

So this allows me to bind touches from `.kv`.

Answer (score 5):

You should perform collision detection. For instance, in a class definition:

```
class YourWidget(SomeWidget):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            do_stuff()
```

Edit: Actually, your method won't work anyway because the Button overlaps the BoxLayout. I would probably instead create a BoxLayout subclass and override on_touch_down, calling super first then if it returns False (indicating the touch hasn't been used yet) doing the BoxLayout interaction.

Answer (score 1):

Methods for binding touch events via `.kv` file/string syntax are possible, here's an example that modifies the caller's background when collisions are detected.

```
<cLabel@Label>:
    padding: 5, 10
    default_background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
    selected_background_color: 0, 1, 0, 1
    on_touch_down:
        ## First & second arguments passed when touches happen
        caller = args[0]
        touch = args[1]
        ## True or False for collisions & caller state
        caller_touched = caller.collide_point(*touch.pos)
        background_defaulted = caller.background_color == caller.default_background_color
        ## Modify caller state if touched
        if caller_touched and background_defaulted: caller.background_color = self.selected_background_color
        elif caller_touched and not background_defaulted: caller.background_color = caller.default_background_color

    background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: self.background_color
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

And for completeness, here's how to use the above code within a layout that is touch activated only if none of the children (or grandchildren and so on) have also collided with the same event.

```
<cGrid@GridLayout>:
    on_touch_down:
        caller = args[0]
        touch = args[1]
        caller_touched = caller.collide_point(*touch.pos)
        spawn_touched = [x.collide_point(*touch.pos) for x in self.walk(restrict = True) if x is not self]
        ## Do stuff if touched and none of the spawn have been touched
        if caller_touched and True not in spawn_touched: print('caller -> {0}\ntouch -> {1}'.format(caller, touch))
    cols: 2
    size_hint_y: None
    height: sorted([x.height + x.padding[1] for x in self.children])[-1]
    cLabel:
        text: 'Foo'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1]
    cLabel:
        text: 'Bar'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1] * 2
```

> I may have gotten the `texture_size`'s backwards, or perhaps not, but the height trickery can be ignored for the most part as it's purpose is to aid in making the parent layout more clickable.
>
> The color changing and printing of caller & touch objects should be replaced with `do_stuff()` or similar methods, as they're there to make the example self contained, and show another way handling caller saved state when touched.

Comment: I had no idea something like this was possible in kv lang -- where I can find more information about the kv lang syntax and what's possible? The docs I could find on kivy.org are pretty lacking when it comes to this stuff.

Comment: It has been a while but if I remember correctly, reading bits of the official source code was super helpful with figuring out what was possible, as well as plenty of experimentation to confirm suspicions.